# Charting in vb.net form using excel data source

Tags: vb.net, excel, charts

I have a form in which there is a button & chart object. I have an excel sheet which I am populating dynamically. Columns C & D have headers "EOS" & "Count" in cells C1 & D1 respectively. The data filling starts C2 & D2 onwards till variable number of rows.

What I want is, when the button n form is clicked, a simple bar chart is displayed in the cart area. the chart should have X-axis as C2, C3, ....,Cn values and Y-axis as D2, D3, ....,Dn values. I have the following code from this [page](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/10/18/charting-with-vb-net-2010/) that does what I need but uses an Access db as source.

Can anyone please show me how to achieve it using `excel sheet` as data source?

```
'~~> Code to generate the chart
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal _
e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim strConn As String = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & TextBox1.Text & _
    ";Persist Security Info=False;"

    Dim tblFields As String = "SELECT * from Table1"

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(strConn)
    Dim oCmd As New OleDbCommand(tblFields, conn)
    Dim oData As New OleDbDataAdapter(tblFields, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    conn.Open()
    oData.Fill(ds, "Table1")
    conn.Close()

    Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Table1")
    Dim Series1 As Series = Chart1.Series("Series1")
    Series1.Name = "Sales"
    Chart1.Series(Series1.Name).XValueMember = "nFruits"
    Chart1.Series(Series1.Name).YValueMembers = "nSales"

    Chart1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(780, 350)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples of reading from Excel

**Reading and writing an Excel file using VB.NET**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18073/Reading-and-writing-an-Excel-file-using-VB-NET

**Read data from an Excel workbook in Visual Basic .NET**
http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_read_excel.html

**VB.NET Excel**
http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel-vbnet

**Also library written in C# for reading Microsoft Excel files ('97-2007)**
http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I got it working ! The error was because I was not supplying absolute path of the excel file. Here is the code:

```
Dim strConn As String = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Temp\EOS123.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""

    Dim tblFields As String = "SELECT EOS, Count from [Sheet1$]"

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(strConn)
    Dim oCmd As New OleDbCommand(tblFields, conn)
    Dim oData As New OleDbDataAdapter(tblFields, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    conn.Open()
    oData.Fill(ds, "Sheet1")
    conn.Close()

    Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Sheet1")
```