# Export VB.NET Charting.Chart in Excel.Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, interop, export-to-excel

Suppose I have a `Charting.Chart`:

[image: Chart with some properties]

that I would like to export to an `Excel.Workbook.Worksheet` so that I can "play" with the data later (for example drag-and-dropping more data on the Excel chart etc.):

[image: Don't mind the differences of the curves]

*Please do not mind the differences in the second chart, something as close as possible to the first one would be the optimal solution*

Is there any easy way to export the first chart retaining **all its properties or at least the ones accepted by Excel**, or do I have to go through every single property? E.g.:

```
myCht.Title = myUserFormChart.Titles(0).Text
mySeries = myCht.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
mySeries.Name = myUserFormChart.Series(0).Name
[...]
```

Comment: To my knowledge there's no interface between the .NET Chart object and Excel's Chart object. You would either have to implement your own mapping, or simply change your .NET Chart to use Excel tables for a data source.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do that?

Comment: You might start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528196/charting-in-vb-net-form-using-excel-data-source

Comment: I already saw that one, but still I don't understand. How am I supposed to provide Excel a connection to data that is not stored anywhere in files? That question and answer pose the exact opposite problem to mine, which has IMHO not the same opposite solution.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but from what I gather you have a System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart that you want to convert to an [Excel Chart Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/chart-object-excel) so that you can easily manipulate and play with the data to see how it affects the chart. I think you're better off keeping the .NET chart and changing it's data source to Excel. Add a refresh function so that you can see the chart update when you manipulate the excel table.

Comment: Yes and no. I have arrays which contain data and I have to do both: show charts in a custom userform and save those in an Excel chart. The catch is to be able to let them have the same labels, title, data, colors, etc.

Comment: I encountered same problem and I have replaced

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to some kind of an export function. You want to export your application's chart to an excel worksheet. And you need an easy way to do that. According to [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [excel chart object's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart(object)) there isn't an easy way to do the conversion, they have some similarities but you have to go through every single property.

However, if I was you I would use an external 3rd party open-source library like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) which supports many excel features (charts included) in order to create a solid "export to excel" functionality in my application.

It is not as hard as it seems and it can be relative easy to adapt it in various chart types and / or data. An example code is as follows (don't forget to install EPPlus nuget package):

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Using theExcel As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage
        Dim theDataWorkSheet As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet = theExcel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data")

        With theDataWorkSheet
            'Create the data cells here...
            'You can get the data from your in program arrays or directly from your chart class...
            .Cells("A1").Value = 10
            .Cells("A2").Value = 20
            .Cells("A3").Value = 30

            .Cells("B1").Value = 1
            .Cells("B2").Value = 2
            .Cells("B3").Value = 3
        End With

        Dim theChartWorkSheet As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet = theExcel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Chart")
        Dim theChart As OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.ExcelRadarChart = theChartWorkSheet.Drawings.AddChart("Chart", OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eChartType.Radar)

        With theChart
            'Manipulate the excel chart here...

            .SetPosition(1, 0, 2, 0)
            .SetSize(400, 400)
            .Series.Add(theDataWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1, 3, 1), theDataWorkSheet.Cells(1, 2, 3, 2))
            .Title.Text = "Chart title"

            'all the other required excel chart properties...
        End With

        'Finally save the excel file...
        theExcel.SaveAs(New IO.FileInfo("c:\test.xlsx"))
    End Using
End Sub
```

Refer to EPPlus documentation for more information.

1. [Getting started](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started)
2. [Shapes, Pictures and Charts](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Shapes,-Pictures-and-Charts)

Hope this helps.